# Unpivot table as shown in screenshot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this pivot table

```
Particular_LL   Dr_LL    Cr_LL      Particular_CLL      Dr_CLL      Cr_CLL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loan         3000000.00 3000000.00  Bank A/C OverDraft  100000.00   100000.00
```

I try this query to unpivot the table, but I do not get the proper output:

```
SELECT 
    particular,
    debit,
    credit
FROM
    dbo.Test1 
UNPIVOT
    (particular
     FOR col1 IN ([Particular_LL], [Particular_CLL])) u 
UNPIVOT 
    (debit
     FOR col2 IN (Dr_LL, Dr_CLL)) u 
UNPIVOT 
    (credit
     FOR col3 IN (Cr_LL, Cr_CLL)) u
WHERE 
    right(col1, 2) = right(col2, 2)
    AND right(col1, 2) = right(col3, 2)
```

I get this result:

```
particular            debit          credit
----------------------------------------------
Loan                  3000000.00    3000000.00
Loan                  3000000.00     100000.00
Loan                   100000.00    3000000.00
Loan                   100000.00     100000.00
Bank A/C OverDraft    3000000.00    3000000.00
Bank A/C OverDraft    3000000.00     100000.00
Bank A/C OverDraft     100000.00    3000000.00
Bank A/C OverDraft     100000.00     100000.00
```

I need this output

```
particular          debit       credit
-------------------------------------------
Loan               3000000.00   3000000.00
Bank A/C OverDraft  100000.00    100000.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
SELECT 
    particular,
    debit,
    credit  
FROM
    dbo.Test1 
UNPIVOT
    (particular
     FOR col1 IN ([Particular_LL], [Particular_CLL])) u 
UNPIVOT 
    (debit
     FOR col2 IN (Dr_LL, Dr_CLL)) u 
UNPIVOT 
    (credit
     FOR col3 IN (Cr_LL, Cr_CLL)) u
WHERE 
    REPLACE(col1, 'Particular_',  '') = REPLACE(col2, 'Dr_',  '')
    AND REPLACE(col1, 'Particular_',  '') = REPLACE(col3, 'Cr_',  '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Particular_LL as particular, Dr_LL as debit, Cr_LL as credit from test1
union all
select Particular_CLL, Dr_CLL, Cr_CLL from test1
```